# sql - How to selectively select by combining multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure how to describe my question (maybe title is not proper).

### Here it is:

I have a table like this:

```
item   type stockdate    saledate

1      1    2012-11-06   2012-11-05

2      2    2012-11-06   2012-11-07

3      2    2012-11-06   2012-11-05
```

So, I want to select from the above table.

There are two conditions:

1. if the `type` of an item is `1`, then I anyway show this item
2. If the `type` of an item is `2`, but its `saledate >= stockdate`, then I show; otherwise, I don't show

So from the above table, I want to `show only item 1 and 2`, because item 1 has `type of 1`, item 2 has `type of 2` but its `saledate >= stockdate`, item 3 cannot be shown because its `saledate<stockdate`.

**How can I write the select query?**

I am using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution would be,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (type = 1) OR
        (
            type = 2 AND
            saledate >= stockdate
        )
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1628c/1)

Answer (score 1):

> if the type of an item is 1, then I anyway show this item
>
> If the type of an item is 2, but its saledate >= stockdate, then I
>   show; otherwise, I don't show

```
SELECT item, saledate, stockdate
FROM
(
    SELECT
      item,
      CASE
        WHEN type = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN type = 2 AND saledate >= stockdate THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END ShowOrNot,
      stockdate, 
      saledate
    FROM TableName
) t
WHERE ShowOrNot = 1
```

P.S: I wrote it with a subquery, just for readability.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1628c/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from myTable where type = 1 or (type=2 and saledate >= stockdate)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from [table]
where type=1 or (saledate >= stockdate)
```

Comment: You don't address all the possible conditions the OP stated.

Answer (score -1):

How about this query:

```
Select * from TableName
Where SelDate>=(Case when Type=1 then SelDate else StockDate End)
```